# how to make virtualbox client to use static ip address?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, fedora

I have a **virtualbox host Windows 7** machine with a **Fedora 20 client** and 3 **windows 7 clients** on the same host-only network.

because I **use Fedora client as a server** for my project, I hope I can make it has a static ipaddress. now it can be **192.168.56.101** or **192.168.56.103** depends on the sequence when it is started.

I searched online, all I found are how to set the host a static address. What I need are **clients with static ipaddress within a host-only network**.

Is there a way to do this? how?

Comment: I just googled "fedora static ip" and got 192,000 results.  Did you try any of those?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a static IP in a VM the same way you configure a static IP on any other computer, if you wish.

The simplest way is to add the static IP, Netmask, and DNS information to the correct eth on the computer.

If your router allows static IP assignments, you could also do it that way if you wanted.

If you want this server visible to the other physical units on the network (not just in the virtual lab), you'll want to set your host network to bridged mode (see this part of the VirtualBox manual: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

Answer (score 1):

The IPs are going to be set just as if it were a physical box. The setting for this isn't controlled in Virtual Box management but the guest OS.

Set the IPs in indivudual NICs on Windows in the Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings -> right-click your NIC. (But I'm guessing you already know where to find this in Windows!)